# Angular how to prevent FOUC

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am I using ng-cloak correctly? In chrome the div with help text flashes before becoming hidden. 
If I add

```
style="display:none;"
```

to the anchor. I get no such flash. In my angular class hideHelp is true by default.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right ng-cloak" ng-cloak ng-click="toggleHelp()">Help</a>
    <div ng-hide="hideHelp" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" >
          blah blah blah help.....
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you loading AngularJS? I believe if you load AngularJS after the content i.e. the footer, `ng-cloak` won't do anything until AngularJS loads.

Comment: ng-bind works wonders where applicable, but you'll still get a FOUC. At least it will hide the brackets

Comment: If you're using `ng-cloak` you need to add some specific styles to your `<head>`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: @Miszy add this as a reply and i will accept the answer, it works ideal with that inline style. I misread the docs and thought that was only needed for ngCsp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using `ngCloak` you have to add specific styles in your `<head>` (so they work before AngularJS is loaded).

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak