# how to prevent handlebars "{{}}" from appearing in the UI in an AngularJs Application before actual data loads?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handlebars.js, ng-bind

I have a page, Whose layout is generated based the GET request that returns an array with length in 10000s. So, until the actual that bind to some of the components load, I get the ugly :

```
{{ binding-model }}
```

This creates a shabby look and feel and I am getting feedback from my users complaining about this. 
Isn't there a way to prevent this?
Can't the binding object simply appear as "blank" until the actual data loads?
Here is a split second snapshot of my application screen when this monstrosity appears :
[image: Handlebars All Over the UI]

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: try ng-cloak: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j

Comment: Exactly... use "ng-cloak"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular how to prevent FOUC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108625/angular-how-to-prevent-fouc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into this directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **ng-bind** for this if you wish to have elements blank until the data loads.

For example if you have this:

```
<span>{{someData}}</span>
```

Change it to this and you're ready:

```
<span ng-bind="someData"></span>
```

ng-bind allows you to add expressions not just scope data so you can do lamost everything you want

Comment: I know but I was dealing with already written so ng-cloak seems a more peaceful solution. Will make sure I use ng-bind in the future instead of {{}}

Comment: No worries, what ever is best for you ;)